# How can you add execute bit on a script from inside vim and quit?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there a one-shot command to add execute bit to the shell script you are editing and save and quit?

Comment: You could use `:!chmod +x %` from within vim but I don't know how to combine it with quitting the file.  That also causes vim to reload the file because the buffer changed

Comment: you cannot, unless you save first, or you are editing an already existing file

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no *builtin* command that does all this but it *is* possible to do something similar with `~/.vimrc` and a little work up front.

There's a few things that need to be combined together to solve this:

- running multiple commands together in vim
- executing external command via vim
- preventing vim from giving you messages about the buffer if you modify the current file (including permissions) while it is still open
- defining handy keybindings
- using vim functions

Here, I'm using a vim function from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer#:%7E:text=While%20creating%20scripts%20and%20other,the%20current%20buffer%27s%20file%20name.) which handles running an external command and preventing buffer messages when the current file gets its permissions modified before vim closes out the file. it also defines the command as `:Xbit`.

```
function! SetExecutableBit()
  let fname = expand("%:p")
  checktime
  execute "au FileChangedShell " . fname . " :echo"
  silent !chmod a+x %
  checktime
  execute "au! FileChangedShell " . fname
endfunction
command! Xbit call SetExecutableBit()
  
:nnoremap <c-x> :w<CR>:Xbit<CR>:q<CR>
:inoremap <c-x> <Esc>:w<CR>:Xbit<CR>:q<CR>
```

In addition, I define assume mappings just after the function to have vim define `Ctrl+x` in normal and insert modes as a key combo that will write the file contents (`:w`), run the function to set the execution flag (`:Xbit`), then quit the file (`:q`).

All of this needs to go into your `~/.vimrc` file before opening the file where it  will be used. But then it can be invoked simply by pressing `Ctrl+x` (or whatever else you might prefer to change the keybinding to).

sources:

- [https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer#:~:text=While%20creating%20scripts%20and%20other,the%20current%20buffer's%20file%20name](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer#:%7E:text=While%20creating%20scripts%20and%20other,the%20current%20buffer%27s%20file%20name).
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249275/multiple-commands-on-same-line
- https://balazshobbies.wordpress.com/vim-jegyzetek/napi-vim-bemelegito/vim-map-remap-nnoremap/